# Can every 3-manifold be triangulated?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

One of my classmates was telling me that it is an open question whether every 3-manifold can be triangulated. This was rather surprising. He said that the question as far as he remember is settled only for 4-manifold where answer is negative. If this is the case, can somebody shed some light why this problem is so hard?

Comment: This is not the place for questions that google can answer in 2 seconds.

Comment: Sadly, it DOES appear to be the place.

Answer (score 16):

Every $3$-manifold is triangulable.

This was proven by Edwin E. Moise in is paper ["Affine structure in $3$-manifolds"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969769), Annals of Math. 56 (1952).

Comment: $+                   1$